# Python: What libraries are 'standard libraries'?

Tags: python, import, coding-style, pep8

I am reading `PEP 8`, and in the [imports section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) it says to put 'standard library imports' in the top of your library import section. My question is: **How do I know which libraries are 'standard'?** I.e. where can I find a list of what libraries are 'standard'?

Comment: If this is a duplicate it would be nice if there was at least a link to the other post.   I am on like my 4th or 5th SO post trying to understand this exact question.

Answer (score 7):

Any library that is listed in the Python core documentation for your version is part of the standard library. So anything you don't have to install separately from Python itself.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ for the Python 3 list.

Comment: The question is how are you supposed to follow the PEP8 standard if you don't know what imports are standard.   Also again you can put standard at the top but aside from a comment and/or an extra space how do you know where the standard list ends and the 3rd party or installed imports begin again?

Comment: @StevenJohnson: The standard library is *not that big*; you very quickly learn what top-level names are part of the standard library, this really is not something that you need lose sleep over.